# Minimum spanning forest, where each tree has the same number of vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, decision-problems

Given a connected Graph $G(V,E)$ with weights $w\colon E\to\mathbb{N}$ and $|V|=kn$. How can I find the minimum spanning forest $T_1,T_2, \dots, T_n$ where each tree $T_i$ has exactly $k$ vertices?

I wonder if this problem is P or NP, I am particularly interested in the case $k=3$.

Comment: possibly of interest: case $k=2$ is the minimum-weight perfect matching problem, which can be solved in polynomial time, e.g. via the [blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm)

Answer (score 6):

Note that trees of order 2 and 3 are [stars](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StarGraph.html). Therefore tree partition problem is star partition for $k \in \{\,2, 3\,\}$.

> Two prominent special cases of Star Partition are the case $s = 1$ (finding
> a perfect matching) and the case $s = 2$ (finding a partition into connected triples). Perfect matchings ($s = 1$), of course, can be found in polynomial time.
> Partitions into connected triples (the case $s = 2$), however, are hard to find; this problem, denoted $P_3$-Partition, was proven to be NP-complete by Kirkpatrick
> and Hell. [Partitioning Perfect Graphs into Stars](https://igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Ebulteau/pdf/BBBCFNW-jgt16.pdf)

A weighted version of the tree decomposition problem includes all unweighted cases, therefore it is also NP-hard for $k = 3$. For $k = 2$ the minimum weight maximum matching problem is known to be solvable in polynomial time.